# How to display the probability of which class a classifier chose

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn, classification

- How can I plot the probability of how the classifier decided?
- I would like to represent the probability, because, for my use case, it is important whether the algorithm chose class 1 with 80% probability and was right, or with 51% probability and was right.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                            n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                            random_state=0, shuffle=False)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=30)
# Train
clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Pred
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
# Metric
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Precison:",metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Recall:",metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("F1 Maß:",metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred))
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

d = {
    "y_test": y_test,
    "y_pred": y_pred
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
def f(x):
  if(x['y_pred'] == 1):
    if(x['y_test'] == x['y_pred']):
      return 'TP'
    if(x['y_test'] != x['y_pred']):
      return 'FP'
  else:
    if(x['y_test'] == x['y_pred']):
      return 'TN'
    if(x['y_test'] != x['y_pred']):
      return 'FN'

df['cm'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x), axis=1)
cleaned_list = []
for element in clf.predict_proba(X_test):
  #print(element)
  #print(max(element))
  cleaned_list.append(max(element))
df['value'] = cleaned_list


sns.displot(df, x="value", hue="cm", kind="kde", fill=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with ROC or FNR vs FPR curve? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html

Comment: @Learningisamess thank for the hint! I heard about `ROC` but `FNR vs FPR curve` is new for me.

Comment: It can help with picking the right decision treshold to match your tradeoff between FN and FP

Comment: Are you wanting this with python [link](https://medium.com/computer-architecture-club/what-is-the-auc-roc-curve-47fbdcbf7a4a)?